# How do I send a request to a discord webhook

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add webhook integration for my reminder site, this is my current code and it doesn't work, what do I need to fix?

When I submit the webhook, it gives me the error set for an input with the length of 0.

```
var webhookInput = document.getElementById('webhookInput');
var webhookButton = document.getElementById('webhookBtn');
var webhook = webhookInput.value;
async function webhookRequest() {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(webhook);

        if (response.status === 200) {
            console.log('webhook valid');
            localStorage.setItem('webhook', webhook);
        }
        else {
            alert('Please make sure your webhook is valid.');
        }
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}


webhookButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        if (webhook.length > 0) {
            webhookRequest();
        }
        else if (webhook.length === 0) {
            alert('Please enter a webhook.');
        }
        else {
            alert('Error.');
        }
});
```

Comment: You are not sending a valid POST request to the webhook with all the required fields?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Your code is correct and works, sending a GET to a webhook URL will yield a 200 code if the webhook exists and the credentials are correct. You're likely using a channel link instead, to create a webhook edit a channel and go to:

Integrations -> Webhooks -> Create Webhook -> New Webhook